# How convert angular object to JS object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table, One column by expressing object with an angular ng-repeat in angular

```
<table class="table table-bordered  table-hover table-condensed  " ng-show="vm.CandidatesList">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th sortable-header col="FirstName" style="text-align:center">{{::vm.resources.FirstName}}</th>
        <th sortable-header col="LastName" style="text-align:center">{{::vm.resources.LastName}}</th>
        <th sortable-header col="CandidateTopic" style="text-align:center">{{::vm.resources.CandidateTopic}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="c in  vm.CandidatesList "
    row-id="{{ c.ID }}"
    ng-dblclick="vm.goEdit(c.ID)">
    <td ng-model="c.FirstName" style="text-align:center">{{c.FirstName}}</td>
    <td ng-model="c.LastName" style="text-align:center">{{c.LastName}}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center" name="TopicToCandidate" id="TopicToCandidate+{{c.ID}}"><a ng-repeat="t in vm.getTopicToCandidate(c.ID)">{{t.Name}}, </a></td>
   </tr>
```

now I want to recive the value of the `TopicToCandidate`to js with

```
var topic= document.getElementById("TopicToCandidate+" + item.ID).innerText
```

but `topic` is null because js can not convert the angular object or HTML object to js object.

Comment: What is the content of item?

Comment: I'm not sure your understanding of JavaScript is correct. Angular is written in JavaScript, it is a framework. So when you say `can't convert the Angular Object or HTML Object to JavaScript Object` you aren't understanding that there are only two things at play here. An `HTML DOM` element and `JavaScript`.

Comment: Why do you need to get a topic by extracting information from the DOM? Angular JS is a framework that allows you to bind data to the DOM and allow interactions from the DOM with the data - without ever needing to do any manual DOM manipulation.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You already have what you need contained in the data model

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand what angularjs does in the background. Don't extract the information from the DOM if you already have it in your controller.

So in other words just use it like this:

```
app.controller('candidateController', function($scope) {
    $scope.CandidatesList = [
        {ID:1 , FirstName:"Dan1", LastName:"Doe1"},
        {ID:2 , FirstName:"Dan2", LastName:"Doe2"},
        {ID:3 , FirstName:"Dan3", LastName:"Doe3"}
    ];

    //get topic of first candidate for example
    var topic = $scope.getTopicToCandidate($scope.CandidatesList[0]);
}
```

You might want to check out 2 way binding in the angular docs.